# How to configure Apache CXF/Jetty Thread Pool Size

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, cxf

I tried to configure Apache CXF to use a limited number of threads, but CXF seems to be some kind of automatic sizing based on the number of CPUs.  (I think this because the same config file which works on one machine, fails on another machine with more CPUs).

The xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration
            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
        <httpj:engine port="0">
            <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="2" maxThreads="4" />
        </httpj:engine>
    </httpj:engine-factory>
</beans>
```

However, when I run it on another machine with more CPUs, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not start Jetty server on port 10,100: Not enough threads configured for port 10,100.  Need at least 7 (6 for Jetty selectors and set managers) but only 4 configured.
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:386)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:178)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:48)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBaseBindingFactory.java:97)
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.addListener(SoapBindingFactory.java:901)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:131)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:349)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Not enough threads configured for port 10,100.  Need at least 7 (6 for Jetty selectors and set managers) but only 4 configured.
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.setupThreadPool(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:469)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:374)
        ... 13 more
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For a web server, low thread count maximums are ridiculously bad.

Realistic thread count minimums are calculated from the following system and configuration information.

- Number of CPU cores
- Number of network interfaces
- Number of Connectors defined
- Number of network selectors needed

Along with system behavior information such as

- Number of expected simultaneous connections
- Average duration of connections
- Average duration of requests

A thread count maximum at 4 is *WAY* too low, you would basically be operating on a single core cpu, with 1 network interface, 1 selector, and only ever handling 1 request at a time in sequence. (a unrealistic scenario).

Even the very first Android device (the G1) had a system spec minimum thread count at 19 just to startup, let alone handle any requests.

Some stats, a Raspberry PI handling 2 web browsers, serving static pages (generated html and images from system monitoring processes) operates most effectively at a thread count of 45.

A small production system expecting a few dozen simultaneous users serving lots of small requests is at 100.

A large production system handling thousands of quick API calls is at around 400.

A large production system handling thousands of larger sized responses (images, etc) would have a thread count at around 600.

Point is, never start low, you are only taking a bazooka to your foot *(you are well past merely shooting your foot off*).  Start with defaults, then monitor and adjust according to your system and the traffic you get.

Comment: This is not a web app (in the typical sense).  It is providing a basic web-service interface to a running server process, which gives the user control over the running process.   There is 1 user per server process.  So actually - we only need 1 thread!

Comment: If you are running Jetty, then you are subject to the requirements, rules, and behaviors of Jetty.   It is still in your best interest to not have 1 user per server process, as that happy path is never 100% reliable (from your clients point of view).  1 failed request and you've locked up all available threads for another good request (until that first request times out).  Pick a sensible minimum. inspect the systems you can deploy to and pick a sensible minimum.

Comment: The issue is that Jetty won't let me pick a sensible minimum!   I wanted to configure it to 4 threads.  But it's telling me I can't do less than 7.  But on a different machine, the same configuration file (with 4) is not a problem.  So really what I want as an answer is to be told *how* to force Jetty to use what I tell it, not what it tells me.  (Who's in charge here anyway?)

Comment: Who's in charge?  well, not jetty, as you are using cxf and spring.  Those would be in charge in your situation.  You have no access to the low level configurations that Jetty has to configure that.  So you are stuck with three options. 1) continue to use this abstraction and live with the discovered nature of spring + cxf. 2) file a bug with cxf and spring to expose more configuration 3) don't use spring and cxf to setup and configure your server, use jetty directly.

Answer (score 0):

The threads used by Jetty are computed from the system whose CPU number is one of the parameters used in this calculation.
So, based on system resources, jetty finds it needs 7 threads. On the other hand, in the configurations we find that the threading parameter "max Threads"..
So just increase it:

```
<httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="1" maxThreads="7"/>
```